# ASP MVC Lambda Expressions or Query Extensions?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, expression

I am using a Model Factory to query the related entities from requesting model.
The result is a ViewModel from a given entity.

### Get Data

```
var posts = _postRepo.GetCommunityPosts(Id); // get an iqueryable

ICollection<PostViewModel> result = await ModelFactory.PostFactory(posts, take, skip); //using the ModelFactory to create the viewmodel
```

### Process Data

```
public async Task<ICollection<PostViewModel>> PostFactory(IQueryable<TRDPost> posts)
{
 return await posts.Select(a => new PostViewModel //the viewmodel
 {
  // simple properties
  Created = a.Created,
  Body = a.Body,
  Id = a.Id,
  // related viewmodels
  Member = new MemberViewModel 
   {
     // Member related stuff here
     // a lot of properties and also related viewmodels here
   }
 }
}).ToListAsync<PostViewModel>();
```

## The Question

Having a lot of different Factories which all have the "Member" View Model. This is really a bad style because I have tons code redundancy. Is there a way to execute a function in the query, e.g.:

```
public async Task<ICollection<PostViewModel>> PostFactory(IQueryable<TRDPost> posts)
{
 return await posts.Select(a => new PostViewModel //the viewmodel
 {
  // simple properties
  Created = a.Created,
  Body = a.Body,
  Id = a.Id,
  // related viewmodels
  Member = GetMemberViewModel(a) // is this possible?
 }
}).ToListAsync<PostViewModel>();
```

Read a lot about Expressions all I tried was without success. It would be nice if you point me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tomas Petricek who said this worth words:

> Declaration of lambda expression that will be used by the query is
>   straightforward, because it isn't different than any other C# lambda
>   expressions. The query is more interesting because it uses two
>   extension different methods. First method called **ToExpandable** creates
>   a thin wrapper around the DLINQ Table object. Thanks to this wrapper
>   you can use second method called **Invoke** that extends the Expression
>   class to invoke the lambda expression while making it still possible
>   to translate query to T-SQL. This works because when converting to the
>   expression tree, the wrapper replaces all occurrences of Invoke method
>   by expression trees of the invoked lambda expression and passes these
>   expressions to DLINQ that is able to translate the expanded query to
>   T-SQL.

And reading this article must be helpful: http://tomasp.net/blog/linq-expand.aspx/